# Use jquery to get elements name of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all text of value, then use json to send the value to insert all of price to the database, but i had the problem, i can't get the text of all value where input text name='price'.
here this is HTML code:

```
<input type='text' id='price1' name='price[]'/>
<input type='text' id='price2' name='price[]'/>
<button type='button' id='btn'/>
```

and this is JS code:

```
$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    var myprice = [];
 myprice = $("*[name='price']").val();
    $.post(
        "index.php",
        {
            type: "insert",
            price: myprice,
        }
    ).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        })
});
```

Comment: use `$("*[name='price[]']").val();`

Comment: `.val()` return the value of the first match. Since you have 2 `price[]`, do you want an array or a single value?

Comment: You can use `$("*[name='price[]']").serializeArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to get all the values:

```
var myprice = $('[name="price[]"]').map(function(i,v) {
    return v.value;
}).get().join(',');

//result: "value1,value2..."
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vm1gd4dy/)

Or `$.map()`:

```
var myprice = $.map($('[name="price[]"]'), function(v,i) {
    return v.value;
}).join(',');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vm1gd4dy/1/)

Comment: This will throw an error ;) I'll let you figure it out! If you can't find it, ping me!

Comment: +1 @Karl-AndréGagnon you're quite right. I figured it out and updated my answer -- `.get()` not required when using the `$.map()` version. Thanks.

Comment: @user3558931 I think .map is easy to use, but result is one value 'value1,value2' , can i get the result like this: price[0] = value1
and price[1] = value2

Comment: If you omit `.join()` the result will be an array. Quite easy, right?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get values once, you need to iterate as you need multiple input values.

and use the correct name, change your html:

```
<input type='text' id='price1' name='price'/>
<input type='text' id='price2' name='price'/>
```

and code:

```
var myprice = [];
for(var i=0; i < $("*[name='price']").length; i++){

    myprice.push($("*[name='price']:eq("+i+")").val());
}
```

Comment: That line is wrong : `myprice.push($("*[name='price']")[i].val());` One minor error (probbably a typo) and 1 major error.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon is it corrected now? better to point the mistake here so I can correct it.

Comment: Still missing the `[]` after `price` (you removed it from the `for` while you needed to add it). **Edit:** wait let me test something. **Edit 2:** Yes, definitely need to add the bracket.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i have changed the name in html too. so for given html in answer, without brackets it will work.

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your items (no brackets needed, no change to your HTML) and add them to the array easily -

```
$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myprice = [];
    $("*[name='price']").each(function() {
        myprice.push( $(this).val() );
    });
    console.log(myprice); // e.g., ["56", "42"]
});
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/xhwtLr5o/)

Answer (score 0):

The name is `price[]`, not `price`.